# How to disable HTML element when variable is zero?

Tags: jquery

I use JQuery 2.2.3.

I have this row:

```
$(".disabledIfNoFeaturesSelected").button({ disabled: selectedItemsCount == 0 });
```

This mean that if variable named `selectedItemsCount`  is zero  disable all HTML element that contains class named `disabledIfNoFeaturesSelected`.

But the row is not working any idea why?

Comment: `if(selectedItemsCount == 0){$(".disabledIfNoFeaturesSelected").prop("disabled",true);}`

Comment: What is `.button()`? Is this some plugin?

Comment: What is `.button()` in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Set the disabled property on whether true or false

```
$(".disabledIfNoFeaturesSelected").prop('disabled', selectedItemsCount == 0)
```